# TwitterでC++に関する呟きを探すには

Tags: twitter

TwitterでC++の情報を得ようと思い、
`C++`で検索をしたのですが、
検索結果が`c`が含まれる全ての呟きになってしまい、
うまくC++に関する呟きを抽出できませんでした。

C++に関する呟きを探すにはどのようにして検索すればよいでしょうか？

Comment: https://twitter.com/search?q=%23cplusplus%20OR%20%23cpp

Comment: 確かにこれで検索することができました。ありがとうございます。ただ、可能であればハッシュタグを使っておらず単に本文の中に`C++`と含まれているだけの呟きを探したいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

同じ目的でたまにYahoo!リアルタイム検索 http://search.yahoo.co.jp/realtime を使っています。
ただ正確さはよくわかりません。